# многопоточный downloader python

Tags: python, многопоточность, requests, очередь

Есть у меня ссылка на сегмент такого типа `url =  https://link-to-seg/segments/seg{}.mp4`, 
как вы поняли, если подставить вместо {} цифры от 1 до какого - то числа, то будут скачиваться разные сегменты.
Сначала я написал совсем простенький код:

```
for i in range(1, 10000):
        r = requests.get(url.format(i), headers=headers)
        if int(r.status_code) not in [200, 404]:
            import sys
            print(f'Error, {r.status_code}')
            sys.exit()
        if r.status_code == 404:
            print('[+] Успех, все куски скачались')
            break
        with open(f'{i}.mp4', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        with open(f'to_ffmpeg.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(f"file '{i}.mp4'\n")
```

Как вы поняли, потом я объединю все сегменты с помощью ffmpeg.
Этот код работал нормально,
 скачивал 400 сегментов за +- 2 минуты.
 Но я решил написать 50 поточную версию этой программы.
Получился этот код:

```
def make_request(i):
    for i in range(i, i + 1):
        r = requests.get(url.format(i), headers=headers)
        if int(r.status_code) not in [200, 404]:
            import sys
            print(f'Error, {r.status_code}')
            sys.exit()
        if int(r.status_code == 404):
            print('[+] Успех, все куски скачались')
            break
        with open(f'{i}.mp4', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        with open(f'to_ffmpeg.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(f"file '{i}.mp4'\n")


def runner():
    while True:
        i_val = mdl_q.get()
        make_request(i_val)
        mdl_q.task_done()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import queue
    mdl_q = queue.Queue()
    for i in range(50):
        threading.Thread(target=runner, daemon=True).start()
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        mdl_q.put(i)
    mdl_q.join()
```

Если я получаю status_code 404, в консоль выводится сообщение что всё скачено, и пока очередь полностью не будет отработана, скрипт продолжит получать 404 status_code и выводить это сообщение. Как сделать так, чтобы при получении кода 404, новые значения из очереди не брались, а программа завершалась только когда все старые потоки отработают и какой-то поток получит status_code 404?

Ещё раз, итог должен быть таким: скрипт получает код 404, после этого, программа не берёт новые значения из очереди и ждёт пока все ранее созданные потоки отработают, потом программа завершается.
Если что, я против пиратства, я скачиваю фильм с собственного сайта.
-Зачем?
Просто интересно, учится ни когда не позно.
Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: кстати почему не выкачиваешь через плэйлист?

`https://*****/720.mp4:hls:manifest.m3u8`

Comment: Получаю http-code 403

Comment: посмотри через браузер, может хеш спереди поменялся. вчера смотрел Доктор Кто скормив .m3u8 телевизору с этого сайта

Comment: Да, каждый раз - разный хэш

Answer (score 1):

Апи через пул мне нравится больше, оно компактнее. Добавил 2 синхронизации.

Lock чтоб стартовала (до получения хидеров) одновременно только одна закачка. Также она тормозит генератор последовательности.

Event чтоб сообщить генератору когда последовательность завершенна.

```
    url = "https://link-to-seg/segments/seg{}.mp4"

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool, Lock, Event, Semaphore
import requests
import sys

headers = {....}

lock = Semaphore(50) # 50 - сколько сегментов ставить в очередь
finished = Event()

def i_generator():
    i = 0
    while finished.is_set() is False:
        lock.acquire()
        i+=1
        yield i


def make_request(i):
    r = requests.get(url.format(i), headers=headers, stream=True) # получаем только хидер по одному
    print(r)
    if int(r.status_code) not in [200, 404]:
          print(f'Error, {r.status_code}')
          sys.exit()
    if int(r.status_code == 404):
          print('[+] Успех, все куски скачались')
          finished.set()
    lock.release()
    with open(f'{i}.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content) # докачка самого файла
    with open(f'to_ffmpeg.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f"file '{i}.mp4'\n")
    return i

pool = Pool(10) # 10 - сколько качать паралельно

a = pool.imap( make_request, i_generator())

for i in a:
  print(i)

pool.join()
```

Этот код работает на потоках, одновременно качается 8 фрагментов.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107154/discussion-on-answer-by-eri--downloader-python).